# Maximum time limit Error in php

Tags: php

i develop a webpage in PHP , in that i call a webservice [DotNet] . That service accept two parameters and store the details of the page in to database[For each user the data's deleted].For each user i need to store data . while i use while loop , it shows "".Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 100 seconds exceeded.." Is there any optimization for this ? Please help me to do this . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 3):

Set `max_execution_time = value` in your php.ini file or use the`set_time_limit(0)` function within your PHP code

Comment: It goes long time , But i don't get what i except

Comment: What do you expect? Maybe the reason it is taking so long to execute is because it hasn't been designed properly and is doing more processing than necessary.

Comment: Ofcourse , that webservice can login in to a webpage and scrap the details of that webpage and extract the information and store it into database , this will applicable for each user stored in database

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
if(!ini_set("max_execution_time", 0))
{
    throw new Exception("Failed to set execution time"); 
}
```

Stops script from timing out.